# How do I add identifier columns to batches of existing files?

Tags: r, csv, batch-processing

I am running a computer model that continually generates individual .csv files. Each file has a unique file name that corresponds to a geographical location and experimental treatment. Each file  contains the same data.  I want to combine the files into a single data frame that can be statistically analyzed in R.

The problem is that the individual files contain no identifier to say which location or treatment they represent. There is no way to make the computer model add this information (!?!).

Therefore, I want to take all the .csv files in the directory, add columns to the individual files that identify them based on the file name, and combine them into a single dataframe. I've been fiddling with for loops for two days and can't figure out how to do this.

My version of a reproducible example:

Here are hypothetical files.

```
Site1.Treatment <- data.frame(Data1 = seq(1000,5000, length.out=10), Data2 = seq(10,30, length.out=10))
Site1.NoTreatment <- data.frame(Data1 = seq(2000,3000, length.out=10), Data2 = seq(10,30, length.out=10))
```

A data frame with possible file headings can be created.

```
data <- data.frame(expand.grid(Site = c("Site1","Site2","Site3"), Treatment = c("Treatment","NoTreatment")))
data$extension <- "csv"
data$filename <- as.factor(interaction(data$Site, data$Treatment, data$extension))
```

Identifiers are then added to the data frames so it looks something like this.

```
Site1.Treatment$Site <- "Site1"
Site1.Treatment$Treatment <- "Treatment"
Site1.NoTreatment$Site <- "Site1"
Site1.NoTreatment$Treatment <- "NoTreatment"
```

The data frames can then be combined.

```
All.Data <- rbind (Site1.Treatment, Site1.NoTreatment)
```

I'd sincerely appreciate help with this!

Comment: What's the pattern of the name of the files?

Comment: Its unclear to me where you are finding the problem: mechanically or in terms of design. You could identify a column that separates your csv datasets, say, `Site`, and add that to each dataset as you read them in from csv. You can easily create the data frame from the csv as you read it in and then add the column, standard across all dfs, with the particular value for each df. These are vector operations, so don't require any for loops. Is this what you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the files are in the working directory, we list the files with `list.files()`, read those into a `list` by looping with `lapply`, extract the prefix ('Site1', 'Site2'), the middle part ('Treatment', 'NoTreatment') using `sub`, use `Map` to create the columns 'Site' and 'Treatment' in each `list` elements and then `rbind` to create a single `data.frame`.

```
files <- list.files()
lst <- lapply(files, read.csv, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
v1 <- sub('\\..*', '', files)
v2 <- sub('.*\\.(.*)\\.csv', '\\1', files)
d1 <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, lst, Site=v1, Treatment= v2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your example to create some files, you can do something like:

```
# Write some files
Site1.Treatment   <- data.frame(Data1 = seq(1000,5000, length.out = 10),
                                Data2 = seq(10,30, length.out = 10))
Site1.NoTreatment <- data.frame(Data1 = seq(2000,3000, length.out = 10),
                                Data2 = seq(10,30, length.out = 10))

write.csv(Site1.Treatment, file = "Site1.Treatment.csv")
write.csv(Site1.NoTreatment, file = "Site1.NoTreatment.csv")

# Read and combine the data
files <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv")

do.call(rbind, lapply(files, function(x) data.frame(read.csv(x), filename = x)))
```

Then you can parse the filename variable to extract the information you need.

Comment: I don't think this is the expected output.

Comment: That could actually do what I need it to, thanks. Although having two separate columns - site and treatment - would be neater.

Comment: Yes this just creates the column with the filename, then you can use regular expressions to parse it and create other columns with the relevant information according to how filenames are constructed (cf. Akrun example)

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a set of files in a common directory with common data-elements?

If so, this can be done quite elegantly using `library(plyr)`:

```
# example data:
write.csv(data.frame(x= rnorm(100), y= rnorm(100)), "f1.csv", row.names= FALSE)
write.csv(data.frame(x= rnorm(100), y= rnorm(100)), "f2.csv", row.names= FALSE)
write.csv(data.frame(x= rnorm(100), y= rnorm(100)), "f3.csv", row.names= FALSE)

# with your working directory set as the location with all the files:

library(plyr)
# create a list with the file names and the file ids that you wish
# IE- "ids" should be character vector of your choosing.
l2 <- data.frame(fls= dir(), ids= 1:length(dir()))
l2$fls <- as.character(l2$fls)
l2 <- split(l2, l2$ids)

# read in your files and add the ID column
l_ply(.data= l2, .fun= function(l, ids) {
  x <- read.csv(l$fls, header= TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  x$id <- l$id
  write.csv(x, l$fls, row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE)
  })

# now read in, and bind your files which have the appended ID column.
x <- ldply(dir(), .fun= read.csv, header= TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Actually, yes it does.